# Cut a Date String into Variables

Tags: java

i have this

```
String prueba = "25 - 2 - 2015";
```

And lets suppose its

```
25: Day
2: Month
2015: Year
```

So i wanna get this

```
String year = "2015";
String month = "2";
String day  = "25";
```

The Problem its the "Month" can have more than one character

(example nov has "11" and jan has "1")

and day too 
( can we have day "1" or day "25") so in this case substring its imprecise so i need to cut them stopping in the dashes

**So how can i cut the prueba String into 3 variables between dashes?** Thanks !

Note: Sorry about my english.-

Comment: split it .................

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: @FastSnail The next question will be "How to split a String with dashes in Java"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 methods:

```
String myDate = "25 - 2 - 2015";
```

Either by splitting the `String` and getting the different substrings.

```
String[] comp = myDate.split("\\s*-\\s*");
int day = Integer.parseInt(comp[0]); 
int month = Integer.parseInt(comp[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(comp[2]);
```

Or by parsing the formatted date

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd - MM - yyyy");
Date date = form.parse(myDate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method like this:

```
String prueba = "25 - 2 - 2015";
String[] tokens = prueba.split("\\s*-\\s*");
String day  = tokens[0];
String month = tokens[1];
String year = tokens[2];
```

*Because of the regex, the split will work with any number of spaces
(For example `String prueba = "25- 2 -      2015";` works too)

Thanks guys for pointing it out

Comment: It would be a better idea to just split on "-" and then trim the individual tokens. This way it will work for uneven spaces as well..

Comment: @AbbéRésina I guess you missed the earlier version of this answer. It was only edited after my comment. Click on the edited link and you will understand the context of my comment.

Comment: yes @bot, thanks for pointing it out... but as you can see, i modified my answer so now it works

Comment: @TommyTopas Yes it works. I am pointing out to Abbe that he missed the edit which makes his comment pointless..

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
String[] array = prueba.split("\\D+");
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
String prueba = "25 - 2 - 2015";
    String[] split = prueba.split("-");
    String day = split[0].trim();
    String month = split[1].trim();
    String year = split[2].trim();
    System.out.println(day + " " + month + " " + year);
```